# My server does not want to port forward or be seen with IPv4 via any circumtances

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, ipv4

Hello I know that my english is not that good, and I am pretty much a typo. Now that i got those stuff out of the way I would like some help with my problem. First, in my port forwarding experience nothing like this happened till now. I tried to make a Apache HTTP website (for business purposes) and tried to port forward port 80 on my brand new server i just bought (It worked on normal computers with the same router and the same cable and stuff). After I set-up the server with Windows Server 2016 Database (I don't know if it's needed but I said it anyways) and set up the website in to the server. When I tried to join it via the private IPv4 address it didn't work. I thought my laptop had something so I tried to port forward it. After my attempt of port forwarding my laptop was right it didn't port forward. I checked again the router, everything was right. I rebooted the router and nothing. I don't know what is causing this problem.

I would like some help with this because I didn't see anything related to this (if there is something related to this please give me the link.)

Comment: Your server is running Windows Server 2016? You've installed Apache on it? There's a NAT/router between your server and the rest of the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem! There was a problem with the windows firewall. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Great! Glad you found the source of the problem? What exactly was the issue with Windows firewall? Knowing what you did may help others in a similar situation :)

Comment: There was a problem with the inbound and outbound rules. I had to add the port for both UTP and TCP (I hope I said them right) and allow acces and then it worked.